# Heatmap Plot -- Getting Error

Tags: r

I am looking at this link.

https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/ComplexHeatmap/inst/doc/s2.single_heatmap.html

This first several lines of code work fine, but now I'm getting this error.

```
Error in Heatmap(mat) : could not find function "Heatmap"
```

I'm no too familiar with R.  Can someone tell me what is wrong here?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you run `library(ComplexHeatmap)` ok? If not, you'll have to install it with `install.packages("ComplexHeatmap')`, then try the other code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the following code:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
if(!require(ComplexHeatmap)) biocLite("ComplexHeatmap")
if(!require(circlize)) install.packages('circlize')

# -------------------------------------------------------

library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)

set.seed(123)

mat = cbind(rbind(matrix(rnorm(16, -1), 4), matrix(rnorm(32, 1), 8)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(24, 1), 4), matrix(rnorm(48, -1), 8)))

# permute the rows and columns
mat = mat[sample(nrow(mat), nrow(mat)), sample(ncol(mat), ncol(mat))]

rownames(mat) = paste0("R", 1:12)
colnames(mat) = paste0("C", 1:10)

Heatmap(mat)
```

Does this work for you?

If yes, your problem was that you had not installed the necessary packages before loading them with library. The first 3 lines of the code I provided is simply checking if you have installed the necessary packages, and then if not, it installs them.